# Comments in .resx XML files?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Are comments supported in .resx XML files? I added some XML comments and they seem to be ignored, unless they're inside a `<data>` element after the `<value>` element:

**Resources.resx**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <resheader name="resmimetype">
        <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="version">
        <value>2.0</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <data name="data">
        <value>value</value>
        <!-- comment -->
    </data>
</root>
```

**test program**:

```
namespace Demo {
    class MainClass {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(Resources.data);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above I get the output `comment` instead of `value`. Why?

Note: I'm using Xamarin Studio on a Mac and I can't install Visual Studio to try it.

Comment: Imho this should be opened as bug at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ not stackoverflow question... I just tried this on Visual Studio on Windows and behaviour is exactly the same, didn't investigate why...

Comment: @DavidKarlaš By `exactly the same` do you mean you got `comment` or `value`?

Comment: @DavidKarlaš If Xamarin behaves the same as Visual Studio / .NET Framework, surely a bug report to Xamarin would be inappropriate?

Comment: Probably, but this doesn't change the fact that this looks like a bug and belongs to bugzilla and not stackoverflow is what I'm saying...

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this because comments can't have pictures:
VisualStudio and .Net also display "comment" instead of "value".(see Locals pad)
[image]